# Do two floats in a compute shader being added or subtracted not give the same value 100% of the time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, hlsl, compute-shader

I have a function I call to generate some randomness in my hlsl compute shader code

```
float rand3dTo1d(float3 value, float3 dotDir = float3(12.9898, 78.233, 37.719)){
    //make value smaller to avoid artefacts
    float3 smallValue = sin(value);
    //get scalar value from 3d vector
    float random = dot(smallValue, dotDir);
    //make value more random by making it bigger and then taking the factional part
    random = frac(sin(random) * 43758.5453);
    return random;
}
```

If I pass in an incoming vectors location, all is fine, but if I try to pass in the center point of three vectors using this function into the randomness:

```
float3 GetTriangleCenter3d(float3 a, float3 b, float3 c) {
   return (a + b + c) / 3.0;
}
```

Then ocassionally SOME of my points are not the same from frame to frame (shown by the color I paint the triangles with using this code). I get flickering of color.

```
float3 color = lerp(_ColorFrom, _ColorTo, rand1d);
```

I am at a total loss. I was able to at least get consitant results by using the thread id as the seed for the randomness, but not being able to use the centerpoint of the triangle is really weird to me and I have no idea what I am doing wrong or what I am missing. Any help would be great.

Comment: from memory I'm sceptical that the `exp`/`sin`/`cos` intrinsic functions give the same value each time